# Oracle SQL -- (Procedure of function) that returns entire column

Tags: oracle, function, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions

For security purposes, I want to have an entity that returns an entire column value.

Example of an entity:  stored-procedure, function, table-valued function.

Example:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION simpleSelect  RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
        output1   VARCHAR2(100);
    BEGIN
       Select  (col1 ) INTO output1 from SCHEMA1.TABLE1;     
       RETURN output1;
  END
  ;
```

The above gives the following error:

```
[Error] Execution (17: 9): ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512:
```

What would be the syntax to create the entity and also to call the entity?

Comment: You're trying to select all values from that column into a scalar variable, which will only work if the query returns exactly one row. You could use a collection, which could be with a pipelined function, or a ref cursor, but it depends how you *want* to call the entity - and what you are really trying to achieve. If you're trying to prevent users (other than the table owner) seeing certain columns then have you considered a view that only exposes the columns you do want them to see? Or virtual private database?

Comment: This will be called from an application program.  I can't have it call a general query, because of worries of SQL injection, so it needs to use a stored-procedure or a function.

Comment: If your query uses bind variables to provide any values supplied by the users then it won't be vulnerable to injection. You can also give the user the application connects as read-only access, and if it needs to do any inserts/updates you could put those in procedures and give execute privs for those.

Comment: @Alex Poole:  Nonetheless, is there a way to write the query as above?  I am investigating "BULK COLLECT" but still can't get the syntax correct.  The concern that a hacker could figure out how to use an open-ended query to their own bending is too great.

Comment: That's why you don't have open-ended queries, and instead use bind variables *8-) But like I said, look at a pipelined function returning a table type, or a function returning a ref cursor. The 'how to call it' part will depend on the language your application is written in. [Here's a Java/JDBC example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252457/266304).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option 1: Use a cursor in a procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE simpleSelect
(
  o_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS
BEGIN
  OPEN o_cursor FOR
    Select col1 from SCHEMA1.TABLE1;
END;
/
```

#### Option 2: Use a pipelined function:

```sql
CREATE TYPE string_list IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
```

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION simpleSelect
  RETURN string_list PIPELINED
IS
  v_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_value  SCHEMA1.TABLE1.COL1%TYPE;
BEGIN
  OPEN v_cursor FOR
    Select col1 from SCHEMA1.TABLE1;

  LOOP
    FETCH v_cursor INTO v_value;
    EXIT WHEN v_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    PIPE ROW (v_value);
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE v_cursor;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_NEEDED THEN
    CLOSE v_cursor;
END;
/
```

#### Option 3: Use a (non-pipelined) function:

```sql
CREATE TYPE string_list IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
```

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION simpleSelect
  RETURN string_list
IS
  v_values string_list;
BEGIN
  SELECT col1
  BULK COLLECT INTO v_values
  FROM   SCHEMA1.TABLE1;

  RETURN v_values;
END;
/
```

*Note: While this may be short to type, if there are a large number of rows then you will create a huge data structure in memory and is likely to result in performance issues; it may be better to stream the data to a third-party application using a pipelined function or a cursor.*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lbv7MnDE)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple option; see if it helps. It uses Oracle built-in type which lets you store *strings*; another, for *numbers*, is `sys.odcinumberlist` (can't tell what datatype is your `col1` so I picked one of them). Benefit? You don't even have to create your own type!

```
SQL> create or replace function simpleselect
  2    return sys.odcivarchar2list
  3  is
  4    retval sys.odcivarchar2list;
  5  begin
  6    select ename
  7      bulk collect into retval
  8      from emp;
  9    return retval;
 10  end;
 11  /

Function created.
```

What is the result?

```
SQL> select * from table(simpleselect);

COLUMN_VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SMITH
ALLEN
WARD
JONES
MARTIN
BLAKE
CLARK
SCOTT
KING
TURNER
ADAMS
JAMES
FORD
MILLER

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```